# Loading Hashmap Through JSON

Tags: java, json, gson

Hashmap:

```
public HashMap<Perk, Boolean> perks;
public HashMap<Perk, Boolean> getPerks() {
    return perks;
}
```

How I save (works fine, I'm using GSON by Google):

```
object.add("perks", builder.toJsonTree(player.perks));
```

Preview of save:

```
"perks": {
    "DAMAGE_AMPLIFIER": true
  }
```

How I am attempting to load but isn't working, error is below.

```
if (reader.has("perks")) {
    jsonToMap(reader.get("perks").toString(), player);
}
```

jsonToMap method:

```
    public static void jsonToMap(String t, Player player) throws JSONException {

    JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(t);
    Iterator<?> keys = jObject.keys();

    while(keys.hasNext()) {
        String key = keys.next().toString();
        boolean value = jObject.getBoolean(key); 
        player.perks.put(Perk.valueOf(key), value);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.callisto.world.entity.impl.player.PlayerLoading.jsonToMap(PlayerLoading.java:730)
at com.callisto.world.entity.impl.player.PlayerLoading.getResult(PlayerLoading.java:684)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have to guess `perks` is null and that's why when you do `put` you get a null pointer. Change it to:

```
public HashMap<Perk, Boolean> perks=new HashMap<>(); //We init the hashmap here so we can putt stuff after that
public HashMap<Perk, Boolean> getPerks() {
    return perks;
}
```

Also you might even change it to :
`Map<Perk, Boolean> perks=new HashMap<>();` and use the interface and not the implementation in your methods

Comment: This worked great job, however there are still null values. I'm assuming where it puts into the hashmap it's doing it wrong. Any idea?

Comment: You get nulls in the map? I guess  boolean value = jObject.getBoolean(key);  returns null it might be because of your json or something

Comment: Or probably the iterating on the JsonOject. I don't know the implementation but you should do something like jObject.get("perks").keys()  that's my guess

Comment: The Boolean wrapper for boolean type is assigned a null value when declared, unlike native boolean which defaults to false.

Comment: yeah I guess the problem is that he doesn't get the proper value when he iterates on the JsonObject.